# Convergence of a sequence on the unit sphere of Bahach or Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, dynamical-systems, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach or Hilbert space and $A$ be a bounded linear operator on $X$, and fix an element $x \in X$. Then I want to know that are there any good ways or theories to deal with the convergence of the following sequence $\{ y_n\}$:
\begin{align}
y_n = \frac{A^nx}{||A^nx||}.
\end{align} 
I'm sorry for an ambiguous question.
I welcome any kind of comments.

Comment: If your space $X$ is reflexive (satisfied by Hilbert spaces for example), then the unit ball is compact in the weak topology. In this topology you will thus always find possible limits.

Comment: Such a weak limit might be zero, which might come unexpected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does *not* always converge. As a counter example suppose a finite dimensional space $X = \mathbb{R}^2$, and
\begin{equation}
A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix},\quad x = \begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
Of course $A$ is bounded. Then

\begin{equation}
y_n =
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle{\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}}\begin{bmatrix}2\\-1 \end{bmatrix}, & n=2m+1, \\
\displaystyle{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\begin{bmatrix}1\\1 \end{bmatrix}, & n=2m.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

In finite dimensional spaces, this is indeed the *power iteration* that converges to the eigenvector corresponding to the largest eigenvalue (in magnitude) of matrix $A$, and the convergence rate is determined by the ratio of first two largest eigenvalues in magnitude, $|\lambda_1 / \lambda_2|$.

I assume more than *boundedness* is needed for convergence of $y_n$. Perhaps if $A$ is compact, you may show similar argument for rate of convergence based on the singular values.

Comment: You are right @LutzL, I'll edit the answer.

Comment: I think it is clear that the sequence need not converge, for example even in one dimension you have the linear map $\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$, $x\mapsto -x$ for which the sequence will always alternate between two limit points. I think the interesting question is: When does it have limit points? In finite dimensions it is clear that the sequence always admits limit points, as the unit sphere is compact.